Question regarding Java upgrade from 11 to 17 and its effect on XML parsing using Java DOM document
Considering the following XML
<TestFile>
    <TestHeader>
        <FileVersion>2.00</FileVersion>
        <FileCountry>GB</FileCountry>
        <FileRegion>LND</FileRegion>
    </TestHeader>
</TestFile>

In the past I have parsed using Java DOM to set the default namespace like this
MyDoc.getDocumentElement().setAttribute("xmlns", this.NameSpaceAsString);

In earlier versions of Java 8, this produced a proper XML like this
<TestFile xmlns="mynamespace.com">
<TestHeader>
    <FileVersion>2.00</FileVersion>
    <FileCountry>GB</FileCountry>
    <FileRegion>LND</FileRegion>
</TestHeader>

However, with an upgrade to Java 11, Im now getting 2 default namespaces on the top 2 nodes with one of them being empty like this
<TestFile xmlns="mynamespace.com">
<TestHeader xmlns=" ">
    <FileVersion>2.00</FileVersion>
    <FileCountry>GB</FileCountry>
    <FileRegion>LND</FileRegion>
</TestHeader>

Im not sure what changed that would cause getDocumentElement to find 2 nodes or setAttribute to set in 2 places.

Edit your question and show the code that parses the document.  In particular:  did you call setNamespaceAware on your DocumentBuilderFactory?

Is the DocumentBuilderFactory namespace aware or not?

@forty-two   - namespaceAware is false

@VGR  - namespaceAware is false.  Ill updat ethe code in a few

I am not able to reproduce the problem.  It works as expected for me.  When you do update your question, you should also include the code which prints or writes the altered Document.

@VGR here is the code for printing
String XMLtoString = IOUtils.toString(xmlSourceFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Im just viewing it in the eclipse java debugger.  thats where I see the 2 default namespace values.  Interestingly enough, when I change the code to output a NON default namespace, it only gets set at the root node as expected.  so something like this
MyDoc.getDocumentElement().setAttribute("xmlns:test", this.NameSpaceAsString);
works as expected for me.  Do you think this might a saxon issues?

@VGR Thanks for the update below.  I do have to apologize, i dug deeper into our shared code and we are setting namespaceAware to true.  I missed it earlier

Given this code:
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("JVM version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        Document d = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new File("data.xml"));
        d.getDocumentElement().setAttribute("xmlns", "xyzzy");
        TransformerFactory
            .newInstance()
            .newTransformer()
            .transform(new DOMSource(d), new StreamResult(System.out));

    }


The output for four different java versions is:
JVM version: 1.7.0_352
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><TestFile xmlns="xyzzy">
    <TestHeader>
        <FileVersion>2.00</FileVersion>
        <FileCountry>GB</FileCountry>
        <FileRegion>LND</FileRegion>
    </TestHeader>
</TestFile

JVM version: 1.8.0_282b08-internal
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><TestFile xmlns="xyzzy">
    <TestHeader>
        <FileVersion>2.00</FileVersion>
        <FileCountry>GB</FileCountry>
        <FileRegion>LND</FileRegion>
    </TestHeader>
</TestFile>

JVM version: 11.0.25
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><TestFile xmlns="xyzzy">
    <TestHeader>
        <FileVersion>2.00</FileVersion>
        <FileCountry>GB</FileCountry>
        <FileRegion>LND</FileRegion>
    </TestHeader>
</TestFile>

JVM version: 23.0.1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><TestFile xmlns="xyzzy">
    <TestHeader>
        <FileVersion>2.00</FileVersion>
        <FileCountry>GB</FileCountry>
        <FileRegion>LND</FileRegion>
    </TestHeader>
</TestFile>


Note that it is always a bad idea managing namespaces with a namespace unaware XML processor.
Update:
The "correct" way to change the namespace of every Element in the document would be something like this:
        DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDefaultInstance();
        f.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document d = f
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new File("data.xml"));

        TreeWalker tw = ((DocumentTraversal)d).createTreeWalker(d, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, false);
        Node node;
        while((node = tw.nextNode()) != null) {
            if (node instanceof Element e) {
                d.renameNode(e, "xyzzy", e.getTagName());
            }
        }

        TransformerFactory
            .newInstance()
            .newTransformer()
            .transform(new DOMSource(d), new StreamResult(System.out));


This does not involve "cheating" by adding an "xmlns" attribute to an otherwise namespace unaware document
